# TCL exec command errror

Tags: tcl, eggdrop

```
bind pub "-|-" !tests pub:tests
proc pub:tests { nick host handle channel arg } {

set size [ exec ls -l /home/archiv/pics/*.r* | wc -l ]
putnow "PRIVMSG $channel :size $size"

}
```

I have this error

```
[09:36:19] Tcl error: 0
ls: cannot access '/home/archiv/pics/*.r*': No such file or directory
```

when i test in bash working this

```
ls -l /home/archiv/pics/*.r* |wc -l
result:
71
```

how can use *.r* (wildcard)?
what is wrong? dir is correct, acces is correct. thx to help.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sense correctly: Tcl's `[exec]` does not provide for bash-like wildcard expansion. Tcl can do this more easily for you, without `[exec]`'ing out, by using its `[glob]` and `[llength]` commands:

```
 set size [llength [glob "/home/archiv/pics/*.r*"]]
```

If you still prefer some other shell over Tcl (e.g., bash), then you have to `[exec]` into the shell explicitly, e.g.:

```
 set size [exec bash -c "ls -l /home/archiv/pics/*.r* | wc -l"]
```